# Set Json object in command line instead of event.json on AWS-SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

Normally

I can use this function for `SAM`

```
sam local invoke "MessageFunction" -e events/message.json
```

However I would like to set contents of event.json in commandline

So, I tried this but in vain.

```
echo '{"type": "Message", "user_id": 5 }' | sam local invoke "MessageFunction"
```

Is there any way possible to do this?

Comment: Have you tried?

`
echo '{"type": "Message", "user_id": 5 }' | sam local invoke "MessageFunction" -e
`

Comment: `sh echo '{"type": "Message", "user_id": 5 }' | sam local invoke "MessageFunction" -e` shows error `/bin/echo: /bin/echo: cannot execute binary file` and `echo '{"type": "Message", "user_id": 5 }' | sam local invoke "MessageFunction" -e` shows  `Error: -e option requires an argument`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried piping and it seems to be complaining about extra parameters. The `-e` flag expects a file path as an input. So to answer your question, it seems to be not feasible as for my capabilities. However, you might want to consider piping the event on a temp file using the commands below:

```sh
sam_tmp=$(mktemp)
echo '{"type": "Message", "user_id": 5 }' >> "$sam_tmp"
sam local invoke "MessageFunction" -e $sam_tmp
rm $sam_tmp
```

Looks really dirty but it gets the job done :D The logic is:

- We create a temporary file using `mktemp`
- We then push the event onto the temporary file
- Then pass it to the `-e` flag of the event
- Clean it after session completes

Comment: Thank you. it looks work-around. but it could be helpful

Comment: Hi whitebear, the challenge you are facing is quite interesting and would be useful on alot of CI/CD pipes, you can raise this feature request to the AWS team on their public SAM github repository. Oh btw, I've also tried `xargs` but the sam local invoke command is expecting a file for some reason.

Comment: Thank you your advice. I will do that in github. BTW, I try your idea ,but my script is in another directory so ,It try to find the template.yml in current directly. `Error: Template file not found at /Users/whitebear/MyCode/myproj/template.yml ` . Since, My purpose is trying to revoke lambda function from another django directory

Comment: Just add code to change the directory where the template.yaml file is located brother.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-invoke.html),

> To input JSON from stdin, you must pass in the value '-'.

You can do something like

```
echo '{"type": "Message", "user_id": 5 }' | sam local invoke "MessageFunction"  -e -
```